# Define unit of custom AppInsights metric

Tags: report, metrics, azure-application-insights, web-frontend

How can I define the unit of a custom metric value in AppInsights?

I'm tracking the metric in the JS code like:

```
appInsights.trackMetric("performance.totalLoadTime", new Date().getTime() - startTime);
```

This results in the Diagram like the following. You can see that the Y-Axis has no unit. I want to show it in seconds or milliseconds. How can I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Please vote for the feature: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/357324-azure-monitor-application-insights/suggestions/40420348-units-of-measure-for-custom-metrics

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to specify the custom units on the charts in UI according to the best of my knowledge.